# It seems that there is no PID for the window. How do you kill this PIDless window?

Tags: window-manager, window, xdotool

I am trying to get the PID of a window "A : Fluid Flow (Fluent) - Meshing" [on the right side of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiJcs.png). The commands that I have found are below. They don't work after I have clicked on the window. I want to kill the right side window which comes from the left side window "Test02 - workbench" without killing both windows. The right side window is obtained by double clicking on Mesh which is located between Geometry and Setup of the right side window. However, I am able to get the PID of the left side window.

```
$ xprop _NET_WM_PID
_NET_WM_PID:  not found.

$ xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3
not

$ xprop
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 5, 694, 54, 54
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Ansyswbu.exe", "MainWin"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
 specified location: 706, 52
        program specified location: 706, 52
        user specified size: 660 by 716
        program specified size: 660 by 716
        program specified minimum size: 2 by 2
        program specified maximum size: 1356 by 734
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, WM_STATE, WM_CLASS, _MOTIF_WM_MESSAGES
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x4600122
        bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x4600120
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "A : Fluid Flow (Fluent) - Meshing [ANSYS Academic Research]"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "A : Fluid Flow (Fluent) - Meshing [ANSYS Academic Research]"
_MW_WINDOW_HANDLE_0027d74c_v2(STRING) = "\002", "\003\013"


$ wmctrl -mlpx
...
0x0380000f  0 5159   .                        mymachine   Test02 - Workbench
0x046000a4  0 0      Ansyswbu.exe.MainWin     N/A         A : Fluid Flow        (Fluent) - Meshing [ANSYS Academic Research]
...
```

With the last command wmctrl -mlpx, it seems that the PID is 5159 for the left side window and 0 for the right side window. How could it be 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Try a different tool `xwininfo`. It should say something like `xwininfo: Window id: 0x5600004 "A: Fluid Flow . . ."`

Comment: Here is what I get but there is no PID to kill the window. $ xwininfo

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x46000a4 "A : Fluid Flow (Fluent) - Meshing [ANSYS Academic Research]" ...

Comment: It works with wmctrl and the window id: $ wmctrl -ic 0x046000a4

Answer (score 4):

It works with wmctrl and the window id.

First, install wmctrl if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Second, find the window id with:

```
$ wmctrl -mlpx
...
0x046000a4  0 0      Ansyswbu.exe.MainWin    N/A    A : Fluid Flow (Fluent) - Meshing [ANSYS Academic Research]
...
```

Last, kill the beast with a null PID [wmctrl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553203/how-to-close-only-one-window-of-an-application):

```
wmctrl -ic 0x046000a4
```

Answer (score 1):

The command you want is:

```
xprop | grep _NET_WM_PID
```

Comment: It gives no results.

Comment: @MisterX Does a simple `xprop` give any results?

Comment: Just thought about it. I was editing the post at the same time. Lol

Comment: @waltinator You missed telling to use the _NET_WM_PID number with `kill` command:

`$ xprop | grep _NET_WM_PID`
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 4238

`$ kill 4238`