# Close only one window of a hanging program

Tags: process, kill

I've had two separate windows of `gedit`. In one of them I've tried to open some file and this has made `gedit` hang giving me the typical choice of "Force quit" or "Wait". Continuous clicking on "Wait" didnt help, the choice window continued to pop up. Clicking on "Force quit" would close ALL `gedit` windows, and I had some unsaved text in the other window (which became unresponsive, too, of course). The `wmctrl` tool couldnt close the hanging window by its numeric ID or name (as suggested in [How to close only one window of an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553203/how-to-close-only-one-window-of-an-application)). Neither `xkill` does the desired, it would close one selected window only in the case of a non-hanging program. So, I was forced to click on "Force quit" and lose the unsaved text in the other window. Is there really no way to close only one particular window of a **hanging** program?

Comment: The easy way is using xkill: Open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T), type xkill and enter. You can then click on the rogue window to close it. I’m sure there are better ways - ie identifying the hung process and terminating that in a more elegant way, but this is probably what you need for a stick fix. If that’s what you want I can convert this to an answer.

Comment: I use xkill for that.

Comment: @Will xkill does in effect exactly the same as "Force quit", it closes ALL windows of a program. Once again, I'm talking about a **hanging** program, this is the crucial difference. xkill would close one selected window only in the case of a non-hanging program.

Comment: @SergiusPro - thank you - I've learned something! Might be worth editing your question to say that xkill doesn't have the desired action (just to avoid someone putting that as an answer if these comments disappear).